# SOQL CALENDAR_MONTH() and WEEK_IN_MONTH() Confusion

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I have a SOQL filter on a DateTime field as below

```
SELECT fieldList FROM myObj WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(myDateTimeField)=12 AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(myDateTimeField) IN : (4,5) AND myDateTimeField = THIS_YEAR
```

This returns results for the `myDateTimeField = 2014-01-01 00:00` as well.

```
SELECT fieldList FROM myObj WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(myDateTimeField)=2 AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(myDateTimeField) IN : (4,5) AND myDateTimeField = THIS_YEAR
```

This returns results for `myDateTimeField= 2014-03-01 00:00` as well.

How or why is this happening? 
According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) WEEK_IN_MONTH(DatetTime)  considers 1st day through 7th day of the month as the first week. Also CALENAR_MONTH(DateTime) should returns 1 for Jan, 4 for April etc.

But what is happening there in my case? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like salesforce converts the datetime fields into the organization timezone when it rendering on a visualforce page.

e.g. a record which has the value 2014-02-28 20:00 when querying from Developer Console may gives the value as exact field value + x hours when rendering on UI( x is is the timezone shift of organization). So we need to take care about filters when using datetime fields. [convertTimeZone()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm) also may help here.

Hope this helps some one.